# How to hide menu from dockpanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I want to hide **account menu** in application start, after successful login want to show account menu. I tried this but it is not working, account menu is not visible.

ShellView.xaml

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="18">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="ExitApplication" Header="E_xit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Account" Visibility="{Binding IsLoggedIn, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
            <MenuItem x:Name="LogOut" Header="_Log Out" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
 public bool IsLoggedIn
            {
                get
                {
                    bool output = false;
    
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_user.Token) == false)
                    {
                        output = true;
                    }
    
                    return output;
                }
            }

public async Task HandleAsync(LogOnEvent message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await ActivateItemAsync(_salesVM);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsLoggedIn);
        }
```

***note:*** I am using visual studio 2022, .NET Framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when setting value of _user.token, notify that the property IsLoggedIn has changed.